# Linux and UnknownHostException for a java program

Tags: java, linux, opensuse, suse

On suse 32bits, i try to run a java application, i get this error

java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-7w1q.site: linux-7w1q.site: Name or service not known

i checked my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost linux-7w1q
# special IPv6 addresses
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

fe00::0         ipv6-localnet

ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ipv6-allnodes
ff02::2         ipv6-allrouters
ff02::3         ipv6-allhosts
```

but it's seem ok

Comment: It doesn't look ok to me. It looks for `linux-7w1q.site` , you only have an entry for `linux-7w1q`. You should check the app as to why it's requesting linux-7w1q.site.

Comment: i added: 172.18.1.125    linux-7w1q.site localhost
 to my hosts file, now i can ping both without problem

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows you're looking for `linux-7w1q.site`, but your `/etc/hosts` alias is `linux-7w1q`

Comment: when i ping linux-7w1q i get an successfull answer with linux-7w1q.site, i get unknow host

Comment: Which is exactly what one would expect, since `linux-7w1q` is defined in your configuration, and `linux-7w1q.site` is *not*